# Could not find a custom field while creating data set in wave analytics

Tags: dashboard, einstein-analytics, analytics, data-set

Could not find a custom field in search bar while trying to create dataset using salesforce objects in salesforce wave analytics even though its accessibility is editable.Can anyone please help???
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Hope it helps
Normally you would find the field. 
once check field permission is given to wave integration user